# Humanoid Robot Arm

Tags: inverse-kinematics, forward-kinematics, humanoid

I have a modeling design for Humanoid robot arm in simscape-SimMechanics in Matlab, I am trying to use the inverse kinematic to make a reaching movement for the arm to the target position; however, I want to know if there is a possibility to coding the forward and inverse kinematic using a block function in Simulink becuase all most of the users try to exploit the Robotic Toolbox to get the Forward and Inverse Kinematics and implement to the robot. ( I mean i want to control my own design in SimMechanics rather than using Robotic Toolbox)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [MATLAB function block](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html). Write a script that contains a single function for doing forward/inverse kinematics, then reference it in the MATLAB function block. Similarly, you could use the [S-function block](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/what-is-an-s-function.html). This would let you make a more complex set of functions contained in a block. Within either of these functions that you write you can use your favorite numerical method to solve the inverse kinematics.